# Multiple instances of DispatcherPortlet

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet

I just created a small POC on Ibm sprin mvc portlet and it works fine. But I have a question that has been bothering me. In the tutorial it says we can have same DispatcherPortletor we can multiple DispatcherPortlet with its own applicationContext and handler mapping. I have something like this in my portlet.xml:

```
<description>HelloWorld Portlet using Spring MVC portlet 1</description>
<portlet-name>HelloSpringPortletMVC1</portlet-name>
<display-name>Hello World Spring Portlet MVC Framework Portlet1</display-name>
<portlet-class>     org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet </portlet-class>
<supports>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
</supports>
<supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
<portlet-info>
<title> HelloSpringPortletMVC1 </title>
<short-title> HelloSpringPortletMVC1 </short-title>
<keywords> spring portlet </keywords>
</portlet-info>
```

```
<description>HelloWorld Portlet using Spring MVC portlet 2</description>
<portlet-name>HelloSpringPortletMVC2</portlet-name>
<display-name>Hello World Spring Portlet MVC Framework Portlet2</display-name>
<portlet-class>     org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet </portlet-class>
<supports>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
</supports>
<supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
<portlet-info>
<title> HelloSpringPortletMVC2 </title>
<short-title> HelloSpringPortletMVC2 </short-title>
<keywords> spring portlet </keywords>
</portlet-info>
```

I am assuming since we have specified the portlet-class to be org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet, each time the portlet is rendered it will create a new instance of DispatcherPortlet, so how can we have just a single instance of DispatcherPortlet that will be used for all the portlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming since we have specified the portlet-class to be org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet, each time the portlet is rendered it will create a new instance of DispatcherPortlet, so how can we have just a single instance of DispatcherPortlet that will be used for all the portlets

There is no need create multiple instances of DispatcherPortlet, you already defined DispatcherPortlet that will be route all your portlet requests to Controllers, like in Spring MVC application DispatcherServlet forwarding your request to Controllers. All that you need is create Controller class(classes) and describe spring configuration

part of portlet.xml

```
    <portlet>
    <portlet-name>My Portlet</portlet-name>
    <display-name>My Portlet</display-name>
    <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
        <value>classpath:/my_portlet.xml</value>
    </init-param>
   ...
</portlet>
```

my_portlet.xml like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd>


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package.portlet.controllers" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="myService" class="my.package.services.MyService"/> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And controller class something like this (it can contain mistakes because taken from memory )

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("view")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView index(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index.jsp");
        modelAndView.addObject("attribute1", "Attribute 1 value");
        modelAndView.addObject("attribute1", new Object());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RenderMapping(params = "form=result")
    public ModelAndView doSomething(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("result.jsp");
        ...
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @ActionMapping(params = "submitSomething=yes")
    public void submitSomething(@ModelAttribute("something") Something something, BindingResult bindingResult, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
        // do what you want with form data
        request.setAttribute("result", someResult);
        response.setRenderParameter("form", "result");
    }

}
```

The main idea that you can have multiple Controller classes with different methods that obtains different render/action parameters. Also big plus that you can use spring beans inside controller classes.